# Opening a PDF with online verification on Linux. Unlock PDF given email/password pair

Tags: linux, email, pdf, remote, authentication

I have an email/password login pair for a PDF file which needs to validate these creds against a remote server. This is a normal feature of Adobe Acrobat which simply asks for creds, queries the server and unlocks the file if correct. No problem when one has access to Windows. Except I don't and Acrobat Reader has for some reasons dropped Linux support.

Now, I'm really struggling to do the same on my Manjaro box. The default PDF viewer - qpdfview only asks for a password when I try to open the file and returns a 'Could not open...' error.

I tried to find a solution on google but I have only found a single thread on remote authentication for PDFs (and that did not mention email/password just password).

[Password-protected PDF not opening on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/937408/password-protected-pdf-not-opening-on-linux)

I tried to use PlayOnLinux to install Acrobat Reader but the installation has been hung for over an hour and I don't think it's going to complete. Even if it did suceed I'm not sure that this authentication feature would work. Associated installation notes suggested that the online features do not work.

Any ideas on how to open this file without resorting to running a Windows VM? Thanks.

Comment: I would expect that Adobe keeps destails of that feature secret, so I'd be surprised if there was an open source implementation on Linux. As far as I know, the only way to use a password for a PDF on Linux is static, no online verification involved. So I guess a Windows WM would be quicker ...

Comment: Couldn't find a better solution and ended up running that VM. Pirating Windows to open a PDF in 2017.. Feelsbadman